# Declare my own script to execute file

Tags: linux, unix, bash, shell, zsh

I have two files, the first is 'ax':

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh

print "Params: $*"
cat $*
```

And another one 'tst':

```
#! /home/me/ax
A
B
C
```

When I am in sh/csh/bash shell:

```
> ./tst
./tst: line 2: A: command not found
./tst: line 3: B: command not found
./tst: line 4: C: command not found
```

When I am in zsh shell:

```
Params: ./tst
#! /IW/users-home/e640846/ax
A
B
C
```

Is there a standard way to have the behavior I get in the zsh shell in other shell?

precision: 
- bash version: 3.00.15-(1) release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An interpreted script can not have the interpreter in turn be another script, so the kernel exec*() fails with ENOEXEC.

At this point, POSIX requires that the shell interpret the script itself. SUSv3, "Command Search and Execution", 1.d.i.b second paragraph.

But zsh is not a POSIX shell. Instead, zsh looks at the `#!` line and tries to run that itself, passing it the original script as an argument.  Which is what has happened here -- you didn't succeed in using `ax` as an interpreter for `tst`, handling the content of `tst`; you just passed `tst` as a parameter to `ax`.